# Evaluation of :$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac1n\Gamma(\frac1n)^{\zeta{(\frac1n)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I want to know more about behavior of both Gamma function and zeta function writing them as a power in the form of harmonic series which i got the below form
$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\dfrac1n\left(\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right)^{\zeta{\left(\frac1n\right)}}\right)$$
 which seems converge as shown by [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(+(1%2Fn)(Gamma(1%2Fn)%5E(+zeta(1%2Fn))),+n%3D1+to+infty)  it's seems converge approximately to $1.6$ But no way to get it's closed form since it's complicated , Now i want the exact value of that sum and it's closed value form if it exists however my narrow idea and attempts are fail to get it .

**Note:** The Motivation of this question is to know bounds of gamma function power zeta function for $n$ large enough

Comment: There at least two errors: $\zeta(1/n)$ is not defined for $n=1$ and you put in the wrong formula in Wolfram Alpha (you entered $1/\zeta(1/n)$) and therefore the $1.6$ is most probably wrong. Maple gives $1.18$ for $n=2\dots 1000$ and $1.205$ for $n=2\dots 2000$

Comment: Thanks for that , I have edited the starting sum from n=2

Comment: Replace $\zeta(1/n)$ by $\zeta(0)+\zeta'(0)/n$ and $\Gamma(1/n)=n \Gamma(1+1/n)$ by $n\Gamma(1)+\Gamma'(1)$  to see if it converges.

Comment: I think is diverging. If we assume $f(x)=x\Gamma(x)^{\zeta(x)}$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=0$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f''(x)=+\infty$